# Fixing Aesthetics for Dendrogram Plots

Tags: r, data-visualization, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I am trying to plot 4 different dendrograms on a single plot and divide the data into 4 clusters for each of the dendrograms. However, after running the code, the plots that I keep getting are as follows.

[image]

This is the code that I am using:

```
data <- df[, c(2, 1305:2185)]

data_HC <-
  data %>% remove_rownames %>% column_to_rownames(var = "Name")

h1 <- data_HC %>% dist %>% hclust(method='average') %>% as.dendrogram
h2 <- data_HC %>% dist %>% hclust(method='complete') %>% as.dendrogram
h3 <- data_HC %>% dist %>% hclust(method='ward.D') %>% as.dendrogram
h4 <- data_HC %>% dist %>% hclust(method='single') %>% as.dendrogram

compare_clusters <- function(data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4){
  par(mfrow=c(2,2))
  cols = c('red', 'green', 'blue', 'pink')
  plot(data_1, main='Average Linkage')
  cut_avg_h1 <- cutree(data_1, k = 4)
  rect.dendrogram(data_1 , k = 4, border = cols)
  plot(data_2, main='Complete Linkage')
  cut_avg_h2 <- cutree(data_2, k = 4)
  rect.dendrogram(data_2 , k = 4, border = cols)
  plot(data_3, main="Ward's Linkage")
  cut_avg_h3 <- cutree(data_3, k = 4)
  rect.dendrogram(data_3 , k = 4, border = cols)
  plot(data_4, main='Single Linkage')
  cut_avg_h4 <- cutree(data_4, k = 4)
  rect.dendrogram(data_4 , k = 4, border = cols)
}

plot <- compare_clusters(h1, h2, h3, h4)
```

There are several things I am trying to do here.

(1) Trying to get rid of the two main branches for the Ward's methods so that all the 4 clusters are better visible. Ideally I want to only plot the data from height = 50.

(2) Reduce the font size of all the labels so the names are better visible.

(3) Reduce the gap between the branches and the labels. Right now, the distance between the names and the branches is extremely huge.

(4) Save this picture. I am not able to save this picture and I have looked everywhere on how I can save the picture.

I would be very grateful for any help on this! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. By adding height to all tree by `raise.dendrogram()` may be the options. Or by plot `h3[[1]]` and `h3[[2]]` may helps.
2. By using `library(dendextend)`, use `set("labels_cex", 0.5)`, change `0.5` part to change size of label.
3. Sorry...I cannot find out.
4. png(filename="your/file/location/name.png")
   compare_clusters(h1, h2, h3, h4)
   dev.off()